# Remove focus from the current activity

Tags: android

How would i remove the focus from an activity which has just being installed/started,

so the user's focus will remine on the previouse one? 
(while the new activity remine in the stack and will work in the background)

the prob is that when i start this new background activity, until i wont press back or home, the ui is stuck. and i would like to fix that some how

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `finish()`, and your activity will be destroyed and the previous activity on the activity stack will be brought to the foreground.

Comment: Yes, but the prob is that in this activity i have BroadcastReceiver and also implemented onActivityResult.. stuff which wont be available later when i do finish(); any other idea?

Comment: `onActivityResult()` will only matter if you have just called `startActivityForResult()`, and in that case, you don't have the foreground, anyway. So that is irrelevant with respect to your question. Move your `BroadcastReceiver` to a `Service` or register it in the manifest, so it is available regardless of whether your activity is in the foreground.

Comment: yes, but if i do wanna use startActivityForResult() of this activity.. i wont be able to do it. coz it's already got finish().

Comment: What you want is impossible, then.

Comment: SO You say there is no way to install/start an activity and avoid of it being as the 'root-acitivty' in the stack ah?

Comment: "You say there is no way to install/start an activity and avoid of it being as the 'root-acitivty' in the stack" -- that has nothing to do with anything else you have in this question.

Comment: I`am sorry if i didnt write my question right.. ill re-edit it.